# Nous voilà partis dans les rêveries

Tags: sens

> Je viens seulement de lui exposer un passage des Soirées de
>   Saint-Pétersburg, Joseph de Maistre parle des nombres : <<...Trente-deux,
>   déclare-t-il, est écrit dans notre bouche...>> Je songe au vers fameux
>
> *Le sourire  éternel de tes trente-deux dents.*
>
> <<...et vingt divisé par quatre, poursuit notre auteur, porte son
>   invariable quotient a l'extrémité de nos quatre membres.>>
>
> **Nous voilà partis dans les rêveries.** Les figues continuent de tomber; et l'on décide d'aller boire du lait à la métairie voisine, de
>   ce lait délicieux, tiède encore,  écumant et qui sent la menthe.

This line is from "Patachou" by Tristan Derème.
 I can't understand the meaning of "Nous voilà partis dans les rêveries. "

And why   "et l'on décide d'aller boire du lait
à la métairie voisine"?

And the milk smells menthol?

I am glad if somebody kindly teaches me.

Answer (score 2):

(1) If you're wondering about the syntax, just think of "voilà" as taking a direct object much the way verbs do in the imperative: "Nous voilà" = "There we are", "Les voilà" = "There they are", etc.

A typical rendering of "Nous voilà partis dans les rêveries" might be "There we are, disappearing into (our) daydreams."

But this is a good example of the versatility of "voilà" (and voici), since an equally fair way of putting it might just have another phrase to move time along in the passage: "And then we're gone, disappearing into (our) daydreams."

(2) Your question about "aller boire du lait" isn't clear enough for me to be sure where the issue lies. Can you clarify?

(3) The verb "sentir" takes a direct object (for reasons as arbitrary as any involved in discussions about why verbs don't have the same object structure in English and French). Feel free to insert "like" or "of" in your English translation: milk "that smells like mint" or "that smells of mint".

Comment: Luke, thank you so much for your kind and detailed answer!

Comment: Hi, Luke. I'll delete this comment later. I'm not sure if you've had a look at my newest question, but which one is most commonly used in your region: "hop X / hop on X / hop onto X"? I pick "hop onto" almost by default. I guess my English is BrE oriented, seeing as how I spent some years in Birmingham as a kid.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens "hop on". In rapid speech you might hear "hop onto" but not nearly as commonly, and I think the only time you'd hear it without *any* preposition or particle would be in the fixed compound "trainhopping".

Comment: Oh, I see. Perhaps AmE speakers prefer "hop": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hop I'm wondering if the English spoken in your region is more BrE or AmE oriented?

Comment: Being Canada, it's often somewhere between the two. Agreed that "hop" sounds a little more specifically AmE -- "trainhopping" e.g. sounds like an artefact of Depression era, *Grapes of Wrath* cultural capital.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Also compare the first line of [this classic song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jm8s2VI1-Y) :)

Answer (score 1):

I can try to explain "*Nous voici partis dans les rêveries*", and that just means "*We are now daydreaming*". Maybe all those numbers and the way Joseph de Maistre associates them with various concrete things makes the author feel dreamy, prompts the author to start daydreaming.

As for the *mint*-smelling milk (not menthol, but mint), no idea.

Comment: Frank Thank so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

"rêveries" comes from "rêve" which means "dream" in English. So the use of the verb "partir" here is more metaphorical, they're not physically moving, it's their thought who are going into dreams.

About the milk, the correct translation of "menthe" would be more "mint" than "menthol" (but still, I'm not sure why milk would smell mint ;-) ).

Comment: woshilapin Thank so much for your advise!